# ConfigParser breaking when section header itself has an ]

Tags: python, configparser

I am using the ConfigParser module like this:

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
c = ConfigParser()
c.read("pymzq.ini")
```

However, the sections gets botched up like this:

```
>>> c.sections()
['pyzmq:platform.architecture()[0']
```

for the `pymzq.ini` file which has `]` in tht title to mean something:

```
[pyzmq:platform.architecture()[0] == '64bit']
url = ${pkgserver:fullurl}/pyzmq/pyzmq-2.2.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like ConfigParser uses a regex that only parses section lines up to the first closing bracket](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/feaefc7f60cd3be7bf4ecc2b73e77d2bfe048403/Lib/configparser.py#L563-L567), so this is as expected.

You should be able to subclass `ConfigParser`/`RawConfigParser` and change that regexp to something that better suits your case, such as `^\[(?P<header>.+)\]$`, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointer @AKX, I went with:

```
class MyConfigParser(ConfigParser):
    _SECT_TMPL = r"""
        \[                                 # [
        (?P<header>[^$]+)                  # Till the end of line
        \]                                 # ]
        """
    SECTCRE = re.compile(_SECT_TMPL, re.VERBOSE)
```

Please let me know if you have any better versions. [Source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/configparser.py) code of the original `ConfigParser`.